# Is there any systematic way to factorise expressions of the form $ n^4+pn^2 +q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, quartics

Is there any systematic way to factorise expressions of the form $ n^4+pn^2 +q$

Expression like $n^4+n^2+1$ usually become helpful for telescopic type , when used in the form$(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1)$, but for an expression like $n^4+pn^2 +q= (n^2+an+b)(n^2+cn+d)$ systematic way to factorise it like above (if possible).

Comment: How about using the same approach you used to factorize $n^4+n^2+1$?

\begin{eqnarray}
A&=&6n^4+an^2+b=\\&=&n^4+2an^2+a^2-an^2+b=\\
&=&(n^2+a)^2-(an^2+a^2-b).
\end{eqnarray}

If $a^2=b$ you get

$$A=(n^2-\sqrt a n+a)(n^2+\sqrt a n+a).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course! Always there exist a way to factorize it.

If $p^2-4q\geq0,$ so we can use a way, which is a similar to the following:
$$x^4+4x^2+3=x^4+3x^2+x^2+3=(x^2+1)(x^2+3).$$
But for $p^2-4q<0$ there is a way, which is a similar to the following:
$$ x^4+x^2+25=x^4+10x^2+25-9x^2=(x^2-3x+5)(x^2+3x+5) $$

For $ p^2-4q<0 $ in the general case we obtain:
$$ x^4+px^2+q=(x^2+\sqrt{q})^2-2x^2\sqrt{q}+px^2=(x^2+\sqrt{q})^2-(2\sqrt{q}-p)x^2=$$
$$=\left(x^2-\sqrt{2\sqrt{q}-p}x+\sqrt{q}\right)\left(x^2+\sqrt{2\sqrt{q}-p}x+\sqrt{q}\right) $$

Comment: How do know the way to factorise it.... In the second part

Comment: I'm interested in this type $x^4+x^2+25=x^2+10x^2+25-9x^2=(x^2-3x+5)(x^2+3x+5).$

Comment: @DivMit I wrote it in the general case. See now.

Comment: Thank You so so much

Comment: @DivMit You are welcome! Good luck!

Comment: Just for the record here, both factorisations are based on completing the square. The first is the conventional way of solving a quadratic. The second depends on the middle term being a term in $x^2$. Both can be used in any case, but the function of the condition on $p^2-4q$ is to ensure that the roots are real. There is a third factorisation (to be expected since the roots of the quartic can be paired in three ways). This is obtained by completing the square in constant and $x^2$ terms and leaving a multiple of $x^4$ as the "spare" term.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $n^2=t$ and solve the quadratic which can be factorized.
You can also try this here
$$n^4+n^2+1=(n^2+an+b)(n^2+cn+d)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can derive it by expanding the brackets and making up the system of equations:
$$n^4+pn^2 +q= (n^2+an+b)(n^2+cn+d)=n^4+(a+c)n^3+(b+ac+d)n^2+(ad+bc)n+bd \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}a+c=0\\ 
b+ac+d=p\\
ad+bc=0\\
bd=q\end{cases}$$
From the first: $c=-a$.

From the third: $ad-ab=0 \Rightarrow 1) \ a=0; 2) \ a\ne 0, \ b=d$.

$1) \ a=0\Rightarrow \begin{cases}b+d=p\\ bd=q\end{cases} \Rightarrow (b,d)=\left(\frac{p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2},\frac{p\mp\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}\right)$.

Hence, for $\color{red}{p^2-4q\ge 0}$:
$$\color{red}{n^4+pn^2+q=\left(n^2+\frac{p+\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}\right)\left(n^2+\frac{p-\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}\right)}$$
Example:
$$n^4-5n^2+6=\left(n^2+\frac{-5+\sqrt{25-24}}{2}\right)\left(n^2+\frac{-5-\sqrt{25-24}}{2}\right)=(n^2-2)(n^2-3).$$
$2) \ a\ne 0, \ b=d \Rightarrow \begin{cases}c=-a\\ a=\sqrt{2b-p}=\sqrt{2\sqrt{q}-p}\\ b=\sqrt{q}\\ \end{cases}$ 
Hence, for $\color{blue}{2\sqrt{q}-p\ge 0 \iff p^2-4q\le 0}$:
$$\color{blue}{n^4+pn^2+q=\left(n^2+\sqrt{2\sqrt{q}-p}n+\sqrt{q}\right)\left(n^2-\sqrt{2\sqrt{q}-p}n+\sqrt{q}\right)}$$
Example:
$$n^4+n^2+1=\left(n^2+\sqrt{2\sqrt1-1}n+\sqrt{1}\right)\left(n^2-\sqrt{2\sqrt{1}-1}n+\sqrt{1}\right)=(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1).$$

Answer (score -1):

This is a quadratic in $n^2,$ so you can always factorize it over the complex numbers.

Comment: But that would factorise as (n^2-c)(n^2-d). I don't want that form

Comment: @DivMit only if the polynomial factors in $\Bbb R$, otherwise you'll get complex conjugates solutions, which can be coupled to get two second degree factors with real coefficients, as the ones you aim at.

Comment: @DivMit Well, any (complex) quadratic factor of a biquadratic $$ax^4+bx^2+c$ cannot avoid having (complex) factors linear in $x^2.$